# What is an "Obsolete" Database?

Tags: migration, terminology

I am trying to have a better understanding of the term: "Obsolete Database"

Are there elements that defines an obsolete database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on who you ask.

Is it in terms of new features, etc.? For example, a 32-bit RDBMS system could be considered obsolete nowadays, because 64-bit is common, and most engines run safely on a 64-bit platform, with access to more memory.

Is it in terms of scaling? For example, an old design that doesn't scale well, might be considered obsolete.

A database with queries that use old-style joins, could be considered obsolete, and in this case would prevent upgrades to newer technology without changing the code.

Some wonks like to say that SQL itself is obsolete, that NoSQL technology is better suited to certain problem areas like unstructured data. I personally wouldn't say this is the right use of "obsolete", but that could be an example too.

Comment: Would it be correct to describe a database that accumulates old data in Microsoft Access (2002) to be obselete in that sense?  Thanks for the explanation...

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? If the database size limitations of Access solve what you're trying to do, then keep using Access. If you think you need to move to SQL Server Express, maybe that's a good idea, but it depends entirely on your use case.

Comment: I am trying to migrate data stored in Access/Microsoft SQL server (back-end) to web-based application backed by MySQL database engine called REDCap to utilize the data better by the users.  I am not sure if it is precise to refer at the the Access/ Microsoft SQL database as "obselete " in my documentation, or not?

Comment: Sorry if that's confusing... but I am new to database management terminology and trying to be precise with my wordings ...

Comment: Do you think the Access database I am referring at would be an "obselete" in the sense it is stored in older platform than the "new" platform/database that the data will be migrated to?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a fair assessment. Access is not well-suited to use by more than one user at a time.